# How to do 'InputBindings' in a 'Border' element correctly?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF `ListBox` which uses a `DataTemplate` as `ItemTemplate`. This `DataTemplate` consists of a `Border` and several child elements.

I want to have a common command ('SelectImageCommand') handling a left mouse click anywhere in the `Border` area (any child element or the empty border itself).

I placed a `InputBinding` in the `Border`. The command becomes executed as favoured but the "visual selection" (changing the background colour permanently) does not happen anymore. If I remove the `MouseBinding`, the visual selection works fine.

I was able to implement a not MVVM workaround by adding an event handler for the `MouseLeftButtonDown` event.

It looks for me like the `MouseBinding` is "handling" the mouse click event in the same way as when I implement an event handler and set the `Handled` property of the `MouseButtonEventArgs` to true.

How can I do a MVVM `MouseBinding` which does not catch the click event?

*I am not a WPF professional. Please try to provide solutions which are MVVM conform.*

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ImageItemTemplate">
    <Border Padding="10" Width="325" Height="350"
            BorderBrush="{DynamicResource SignificantInformationColorBrush}"
            BorderThickness="0" Margin="5" Background="Transparent" Focusable="True" MouseLeftButtonDown="ImageBorderOnMouseLeftButtonDown">
        <!--<Border.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick"
                          Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectImageCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                          CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
        </Border.InputBindings>-->
        <StackPanel>
            <Border BorderBrush="LightGray"
                    BorderThickness="1"
                    CornerRadius="1" Height="300" Width="300" Background="Transparent">
                <StackPanel Background="Black">
                    <Canvas Width="300" Height="300" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent">
                        <Image Width="300" Stretch="UniformToFill" StretchDirection="DownOnly"
                               Source="{Binding BitmapImage}"
                               Height="300">
                            <Image.InputBindings>
                                <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick"
                                              Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.OpenOriginalCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                                              CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                            </Image.InputBindings>
                        </Image>
                    </Canvas>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="1 10 0 0">
                <TextBlock Margin="5 0 0 0" TextAlignment="Center"
                           FontSize="11" Text="{Binding ImageInfo.SopInstanceUid}" Background="Transparent" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 4):

Set the `Background` property of the `Border`:

```
<Border Padding="10" Width="325" Height="350" BorderThickness="0" Margin="5"
        Background="Transparent">
...
```

If you don't, the unpainted area won't respond to mouse events.

Comment: Thank you for this hint! Now the command is executed as favoured. But the 'optical' selection now only happens if a double click any free border area. During mouse hover the background changes as favoured but a single click causes no optical change.

Comment: I updated the question and the code. Solution only works with ugly event handler workaround, not with `MouseBinding`.